# How to set MAXIMUM number of record in DETAIL SECTION in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

How to set MAXIMUM number of record in DETAIL SECTION in crystal report
I am making Report which has Pre-Printed Format. 
Which allows Six Lines of row to be PRINTED. 
So in report if i get More then Six row in detail Section then it should be set on next page of report. 
Now say i get 8 rows in detail section then First Page with Six rows should be set & remaining 2 rows should be set on second page & 6 rows blank space should be automatically added in second pages detail section.

I have tried like : 
section expert for the detail section and against New Page After add the formula (x-2) 
recordnumber mod 6 = 0

But it only works when i just have to set Maximum row for Page but 
IT DO NOT ADD ANY BLACK ROW IF THERE ARE LESS ROW IN DETAIL SECTION 
but i want to add blank row.

Ex: 
Order Description Quantity

### 123 Item 1 500

### 124 Item 2 350

---

---

---

Answer (score 1):

This is possible to do but it is a bit of hack.  I'm pretty sure there is nothing built in to Crystal that will do this for you.

First you need to add a new formula field to your report in the Detail Section, with the following formula:

`(RecordNumber Mod 6)`

I have called this formula `mod_record`.

You then need to add 5 new sections below your main Detail section.  Add a single line to each of the new sections you have just added.

In the first detail section (Details b) go to `Section Expert` and click the formula button next to `Suppress (No Drill-Down)`.  In the formula you need to put the following:

```
If OnLastRecord = true Then
  If {@Mod_Record} <= 1 Then 
      false 
  Else 
      true
Else
  true
```

The formula is the same for each detail section apart from one change.  You need to replace the `<= 1` with the following for each section:

- Details c should be `<=3`
- Details d should be `<=4`
- Details e should be `<=5`
- Details f should be `<=6`

This will give the impression that the details section is a fixed width of 6 lines.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Write following formula on new page after property of detail section

if recordnumber mod 5 = 0 then
true
else
false

Answer (score 0):

Barry's Example given above works perfectly... The only problem I had with it is that I was doing page breaks after a specified group. Since Barry's method was dependent on RecordNumber this threw the RecordNumber count off as their is currently no way to reset the RecordNumber on a page break.

I ended up resolving this by placing the detail section in a sub report off of the main report... this created a recordNumber reset as the RecordNumber resets with each sub report link change.

A lot of work to institute something that Crystal should have implemented by now... but I have researched this a lot and have not found an easier way to handle this.