# How to fix Number of rows in detail section and insert blank rows if number of record less than rows fixed in detail section

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I want to print three pay slips in an A4 size page. Page header and footer are fixed number of rows.

I want *Detail* section to print **8 records**. If records are *less than 8*, remaining line should be blank printed and *3 pay slip* print on one page.

Input parameters are *Month* and *Year*. I grouped each pay slip with `personnel_id` and placed the `personel_id`, `name` and `bank account no.`  on group header section.

In detail section

```
Earnings:               Total
Basic pay               20000
Arrear                   1000
Qualification Pay         500
Deduction:      
Medical  Fee             2000
Club Fee                 1000
```

In Group footer

```
Total Earning           21500
Total Deduction          3000
Net Pay                 18500
```

Sometimes *Earning* has only one record and sometimes *deduction* has only one record.
I want to fix detail section with 8 or 10 rows and also 2 or 3 pay slips in one A4 size page.
Thanks.

Sample Data

```
E=Earnings
D=Deductions
Personnel  ID   EDname          Cur_amount  EDCode  EDtype  P_Month  P_Year
17777-7      Basic Pension         20000     401       E       4       2014
17777-7         Arrear             1000      402       E       4       2014
17777-7     Qualification Alw.     5000      403       E       4        2014
17777-7      Medical Fee           2000      501       D       4       2014
17777-7       Club Fee             1000      502       D       4       2014
18888-8      Medical Fee           1500      501       D       4       2014
18888-8        Club Fee            700        502      D       4       2014
```

Report format on one page id just like below

```
Personnel_id:18888-8                              Pay Slip
 Name:            xyz                             Month  April, 2014   //`Group Header`
Account_No. 123444
Deduction:
Medical Fee                      1500.00
Club Fee                         700.00                       // `Detail Section`
Total Earning:                    0.00                       //    `Group Footer` 
Total Deduction:                 -2200.00
Net pay                         -2200.00
```

---

```
Personnel_id:17777-7                              Pay Slip
 Name:            ABC                             Month  April, 2014
Account_No. 123456
 Earnings:                                      
Basic Pension                 20000.00                    
Arrear                        1000.00
Qualification Alw.            5000.00  
Deduction:
Medical Fee                   2000.00
Club Fee                      1000.00
Total Earning:                21500.00
Total Deduction:              3000.00
Net pay                       18500.00
```

---

according to your formula result of first pay slip is

```
Personnel_id:18888-8                              Pay Slip
 Name:            xyz                             Month  April, 2014
Account_No. 123444

 Earnings:                                      
Basic Pension                                    
Arrear                             
Qualification Alw.           
Deduction:
Medical Fee                      1500.00
Club Fee                         700.00
Total Earning:                   0.00

Total Deduction:                -2200.00
Net pay                          -2200.00
```

needed remaining 6 blank  lines in detail section after Club fee

Answer (score 0):

since detail section is fixed to 8 rows..

1. Simple way is to create `8 detail` sections and place each field in one detail section.
2. Write a formula that will extend to the end of the detail section. Here write your code to print a line or leave it if you need a empty space.

   ```
   if ISNULL(databasefiled)
   then "--------------------------------------------------"
   else totext(databasefield.value)
   ```

Comment: what is the problem? where it is getting struck?

Comment: I edited my question . read carefully and do the needful. Thanks.

Comment: Have you added 7 or 8 detail sections? because if you have added then I am sure you will be able to see blank lines by using the formula in my answer..and coming to 3 pay slips you need to take 3 sub reports in main report and dedicate one sub report for one payslip.. your formatting is not good I have again formatted your `EDIT`

Comment: with the help of this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483252/how-to-set-maximum-number-of-record-in-detail-section-in-crystal-report

Comment: i have stuck here If OnLastRecord = true Then
  If {@Mod_Record} <= 1 Then 
      false 
  Else 
      true
Else
  true  because in my query return more than 1000 records. above method bases on onlastrecord. any substitute of this ?

Comment: The solution that you are using is a bit complicated and I am not sure how this works because there is no sure that recordnumber should be `1,2.....' when there is grouping then record number will be not regular but can be jumbled...Its up to which solution you want to use.

Comment: no no its your wish... you can use any approach but it was my experience i faced while using `record number` I used it in alternate coliuring but that was a big flop for me... Its up to you if you wish discard my solution...no problem

Answer (score 0):

1)First of all fix height of detail section 
by right click on detail section ->section expert->New Page Before checked->beside button of (x+2) write formula of ->
IF Remainder (RecordNumber, 8) = 0 THEN
    TRUE
ELSE
    FALSE

2)under detail section (suppose section3) is your detail section 
  then leave report section blank with needed space and else for footer put it in
page footer .. i think this will solve your problem.. mine is solved..